DeviceActivityCenter startMonitoring hangs intermittently in iOS 18
I'm encountering an issue with DeviceActivityCenter where my app sometimes gets hung up on the following lines:
center.stopMonitoring()
center.startMonitoring(.locked, during: defaultSchedule, events: events)
center.startMonitoring(.unlocked, during: schedule, events: events)

This behavior occurs inconsistently, approximately 50% of the time, and causes a delay before the monitoring starts. Eventually, the code does execute, but it can hang for several seconds. This issue is new to iOS 18—it never occurred in iOS 17.
It hangs intermittently on the calls to stopMonitoring() and startMonitoring(). I added print() statements to confirm that this is where the delay occurs.
Has anyone else experienced this with iOS 18? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!
Additional Info:
Issue started after upgrading to iOS 18.
Happens about 50% of the time, with no clear pattern.
No changes were made to this part of the code between iOS 17 and iOS 18.
This delay can last for up to a minute before it proceeds.
Here is my code:
import DeviceActivity
import SwiftUI

extension DeviceActivityName {
    static let locked = Self("locked")
    static let unlocked = Self("unlocked")
}

extension DeviceActivityEvent.Name {
    static let locked = Self("locked")
    static let unlocked = Self("unlocked")
}

class MySchedule {
    static let shared = MySchedule()
    let center = DeviceActivityCenter()
    
    
    @AppStorage("unlockedStartDate", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.app.appname")) private var unlockedStartDateData: Data?
    var unlockedStartDate: Date? {
        get {
            if let data = unlockedStartDateData {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let decodedDate = try? decoder.decode(Date.self, from: data) {
                    return decodedDate
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let newDate = newValue {
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                if let encodedData = try? encoder.encode(newDate) {
                    unlockedStartDateData = encodedData
                } else {
                    unlockedStartDateData = nil
                }
            } else {
                unlockedStartDateData = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    @AppStorage("unlockedEndDate", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.app.appname")) private var unlockedEndDateData: Data?
    var unlockedEndDate: Date? {
        get {
            if let data = unlockedEndDateData {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let decodedDate = try? decoder.decode(Date.self, from: data) {
                    return decodedDate
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let newDate = newValue {
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                if let encodedData = try? encoder.encode(newDate) {
                    unlockedEndDateData = encodedData
                } else {
                    unlockedEndDateData = nil
                }
            } else {
                unlockedEndDateData = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Save schedule start and end times
    public func setSchedule(timeLimitMinutes: Int = 0) {
        print("center.stopMonitoring().start")
        center.stopMonitoring([.locked, .unlocked])
        print("center.stopMonitoring().complete")
        
        if timeLimitMinutes == 0 {
            // Schedule to block apps (locked state)
            let startTime = DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0)
            let endTime = DateComponents(hour: 23, minute: 59)
            let defaultSchedule = DeviceActivitySchedule(
                intervalStart: startTime,
                intervalEnd: endTime,
                repeats: true
            )
            
            unlockedStartDate = nil
            unlockedEndDate = nil
            
            let events: [DeviceActivityEvent.Name: DeviceActivityEvent] = [
                .locked: DeviceActivityEvent(
                    applications: MyModel.shared.selectionToDiscourage.applicationTokens,
                    categories: MyModel.shared.selectionToDiscourage.categoryTokens,
                    webDomains: MyModel.shared.selectionToDiscourage.webDomainTokens,
                    threshold: DateComponents(minute: timeLimitMinutes)
                )
            ]
            
            do {
                print("center.startMonitoring(.locked).start")
                try center.startMonitoring(.locked, during: defaultSchedule, events: events)
                print("center.startMonitoring(.locked).complete")
            } catch {
                print("Error starting locked schedule: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } else {
            // Schedule to unlock apps (unlocked state)
            let schedule = getUnlockedSchedule(forMinutes: timeLimitMinutes)
            
            let events: [DeviceActivityEvent.Name: DeviceActivityEvent] = [
                .unlocked: DeviceActivityEvent(threshold: DateComponents(minute: timeLimitMinutes))
            ]
            
            do {
                print("center.startMonitoring(.unlocked).start")
                try center.startMonitoring(.unlocked, during: schedule, events: events)
                print("center.startMonitoring(.unlocked).complete")
            } catch {
                print("Error starting unlocked schedule: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Create a schedule based on the current time and specified minutes
    func getUnlockedSchedule(forMinutes minutes: Int) -> DeviceActivitySchedule {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentDate = Date()
        
        // Start is now
        let startComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate)
        
        // End is 'minutes' from now
        let intervalEnd = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: currentDate)!
        let endComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: intervalEnd)
        
        unlockedStartDate = currentDate
        unlockedEndDate = intervalEnd
        
        return DeviceActivitySchedule(
            intervalStart: startComponents,
            intervalEnd: endComponents,
            repeats: false
        )
    }
    
    // Check if the current time is within the schedule
    func isScheduleUnlocked() -> Bool {
        let now = Date()
        guard let intervalStartDate = unlockedStartDate, let intervalEndDate = unlockedEndDate else { return false }
        
        return now >= intervalStartDate && now <= intervalEndDate
    }
}

